# cocos2d and MPMoviePlayerController crash

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I try to show an intro and replaceScene when the intro has finished. But, when the movie finish, app is crashing on [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCFadeTransition transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[MenuScene scene]]];.

code is;

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish {
```

[self.moviePlayer stop];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCFadeTransition transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[MenuScene scene]]];
}

-(id) init
{

// always call "super" init
 // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
 if( (self=[super init] )) {
  //pencere boyutu elde ediliyor

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"mp4"]];
  self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

// Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
              name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
               object:self.moviePlayer];

if ([self.moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
   // Use the new 3.2 style API
   self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
   self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
   // This does blows up in cocos2d, so we'll resize manually
   // [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
   [self.moviePlayer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((float)M_PI_2)];
   CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
   self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, winSize.height, winSize.width);// width and height are swapped after rotation
   [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
  } else {
   // Use the old 2.0 style API
   self.moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
   [self.moviePlayer play];
  }

}

return self;
}

Answer (score 0):

This line:
selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)

should be:
selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish)

Answer (score 0):

CCScene* scene = [AboutLayer scene];

```
CCTransitionFade* transitionScene = [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.1 scene:scene withColor:ccWHITE];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:transitionScene];
```